# External display mirroring builtin on Lenovo G560

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo, external-monitor

On a `Lenovo G560` running Ubuntu 14.10 I am trying to connect an external monitor to use as a dual-monitor setup. When connecting the display, the external monitor one *mirrors* what is on the builtin display. I need it to function as an additional screen.

I have searched for a monitor mirror option in the BIOS, but there is no such related function in the BIOS. From googling I see that on Windows [it is said](https://www.technibble.com/forums/threads/lenovo-g560-laptop-screen-will-not-switch.27492/) that pressing `FN-F3` should provide the user with 4 options:

- 1st option which is already selected is computer only
- 2nd option is duplicate
- 3rd is extend
- 4th is projector

However, on this Ubuntu install I do not get that popup, possibly due to a missing ACPI driver. I have checked in KDE's built-in `System Settings -> Display and Monitor` configuration, but the options for configuring multiple monitors are not there. From casual googling I cannot locate the proper driver to install. This is the graphics information in use:

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   50.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

A colleague with the exact same model laptop and the same Ubuntu version successfully uses his external display as a second monitor. We are both stumped as to why this particular computer only mirrors the display.

Comment: your graphics is Intel or Nvidia?

Comment: Update your question with the output of the command `xrandr -q`

Comment: Sorry for asking, but did you try System Settings > Screens, see if mirroring is checked? If so, simply uncheck :)

Comment: @NewUSer: Thank you, I have updated the question with the information.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I'm using the KDE desktop, and I have checked the relevant place there but only one screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

display settings doesn't have much with BIOS settings, to change output from mirror to dual screen you have to go to "System Settings" then to "Display and Monitor" (I think that it has same name in Ubuntu and Kubuntu), click on monitor and set resolution and position (drag second monitor icon to the left or right of first one). There you have also an option to mirror displays that you have to uncheck.

Comment: Thank you knjigor. On my colleague's KDE system it fact we do see the second monitor in Display and Monitor. On my system there is no second display there, even though `xrandr` does see it.

Comment: Ok, try to  go to display settings again and grab icon of monitor that is listed with your left mouse button and move it to left or right. Some times monitors are placed one above other and that is setting for mirroring in Kubuntu, and because your resolution is 1366x768 it might be that primary display is above secondary with smaller resolution 1024x768. If this is a case, move bigger display to left and smaller to right and it should solve a problem.

Comment: My Display Settings is empty, I only see there a gray screen.

Comment: And did you try to move it to left or right?

Comment: There's nothing to move - no icons,  only a gray screen. And just moving the screen - yes I tried..